# image uri is different in android and web

Tags: android, react-native, web, expo, imagepicker

I need help here.

I am using `expo-image-picker`. When I select an image, the image URI is different in the android app and in web i.e. when I pick an image in the android app the image URI is like below

```
file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252FDataStreet-dc8e0d36-942b-4031-8cde-a7c936aeef58/ImagePicker/786d58b2-fa4a-49bd-b606-6c22e478ea49.jpg
```

But the same code gives the below image URI when I select an image in the web(Browser)

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QBKRXhpZgAASUkqABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAMQECAB8AAAAiAAAAAAAAAEFkb2JlIFBob3Rvc2hvcCAyMS4xIChXaW5kb3dzKQAA/+ENnWh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC8APD94cGFja2V0IGJlZ2luPSLvu78iIGlkPSJXNU0wTXBDZWhpSHpyZVN6TlRjemtjOWQiPz4gPHg6eG1wbWV0YSB4bW...
```

But I want the same URI as `file:///data/user/0/host....`. How can I do this?

Thanks.

You can reproduce it here https://snack.expo.io/0vZrA4ias

Step to reproduce

Once select an image in Android mode and check `Log` and then upload the image in `web` mode.

Comment: what you mean by same code? are u converting it ? show your implementation

Comment: @MajidAli Thanks for your time. I am testing it here https://snack.expo.io/0vZrA4ias and have implemented the same code. You can refer to the same.